# Retrieve specific fields of a parent table from a child table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about the SQL statement necessary to acquire data of a parent table from a child one. I'm currently using MySQL. An example of the structure of the DB is:

```
State (PK id, name)
County (PK id, FK id_state, name)
City (PK id, FK id_county, name)
Citizen (PK id, FK id_city, identificationID, name, surname)
```

How can I obtain all the id of the citizen with also the name of the state which does not belong to the Citizen table?
Do I need to use a where condition on the multiple tables or there is a quicker way to accomplish it?

I found only this laborious solution which works correctly:

```
SELECT Citizen.id, State.name
FROM State, County, City, Citizen
WHERE Citizen.id_city = City.id 
AND City.id_county = County.id 
AND County.id_state = State.id
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient and brief solution than declaring multiple where conditions. Especially because each table has many records and doing all the joins could require a lot of time.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: You need each join you do here. However, with proper indexing it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Instead, if i have a specific citizen, and i want to show all the citizen belonging to the same state, do i need firstly to recover the state id and then filter the citizen for the state? I mean this: SELECT Citizen.id, State.name FROM State, County, City, Citizen WHERE Citizen.id_city = City.id AND City.id_county = County.id AND County.id_state = State.id AND State.id IN (SELECT Distinct State.id FROM State, County, City, Citizen WHERE Citizen.id ="1234" AND Citizen.id_city = City.id AND City.id_county = County.id AND County.id_state = State.id)

Comment: I mean `FROM Citizen JOIN City ON Citizen.id_city = City.id JOIN County ON etc.`, i.e. proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax. (The way to join since 1992...)

Comment: Okay, i get the need to use the JOIN syntax instead of the where condition, but i want to know if the overall logic is correct or not.

Comment: Try it and see if it works